# Recovering Chrome Passwords from Login Data File, Without Local State File

Tags: chrome, decryption

I ran the ForensIT profile migration wizard which migrates an existing profile to a new environment (from domain to workgroup, or vice versa). Doing so deletes encryption keys from Chrome's "Local State" file, similar to changing a password, and Chrome lost the saved passwords. When the user logs in from the migrated profile, Local State's encryption key is replaced, so tools like Chromepass don't work, as it tries to use the new Local State encryption key.

I know the password from the old environment\profile, but switching the profile back still assigns a different SID. Am I screwed without the Local State file? Is there at least a way to find the encryption key? I can then add that to the  Local State file and then use the user's password to decrypt it.